# gather with dataframe behaves differently after lapply

Tags: r, dplyr, lapply

When I apply `lapply`, something changed in my dataset and `gather` (from `dplyr`) does not work. Here's a minimum working example:

```
employee<- c('John','Peter','Mary',"Kate")
salarypre <- c(-1,23.5,33.2,34)
salarypost <- c(51,25.2,53,24.3)
startdate <- as.Date(c('2010-11-1','2008-3-25','2007-3-14','2008-3-12'))
mydata<-data.frame(employee,salarypre,salarypost,startdate)
mydata.big<-gather(mydata,feature,val,salarypre,salarypost)
View(mydata.big)
```

However, let's say that the `-1` in `salarypre` should be treated as `NA`, as should all negative values. It makes sense to apply a function to convert all negative values to `NA` in my dataset. So I did:

```
mydata<-lapply(mydata,function(x) ifelse(is.numeric(x) & x<0,NA,x))
```

Now, however, I can't use gather:

```
> mydata.big<-gather(mydata,feature,val,salarypre,salarypost)
Error: is.character(x) is not TRUE
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

*lapply* returns a list, wrap it with *data.frame* function to convert, then *gather* should work as expected:

```
mydata <- data.frame(lapply(mydata, function(x) ifelse(is.numeric(x) & x < 0, NA, x)))

gather(mydata, feature, val, salarypre, salarypost)

#   employee startdate    feature  val
# 1        1     14914  salarypre   NA
# 2        4     13963  salarypre 23.5
# 3        3     13586  salarypre 33.2
# 4        2     13950  salarypre 34.0
# 5        1     14914 salarypost 51.0
# 6        4     13963 salarypost 25.2
# 7        3     13586 salarypost 53.0
# 8        2     13950 salarypost 24.3
```

---

**Edit:** To avoid *apply*, we could use *mutate_if* with custom function:

```
myFun <- function(x){ifelse(x < 0, NA, x)}

mydata %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, myFun) %>% 
  gather(feature, val, salarypre, salarypost)
```